# Test Visibility of Angular Component

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there a way for me, using `offsetParent`, during unit testing using Jasmine/Karma to tell whether or not a component is visible?

If I have some component:

`<my-component *ngIf="some condition"></my-component>`

I'd like to write a test that will check if the component is visible if `some condition` is true.

I was trying something like:

```
// Assert
expect(ftuFixture.nativeElement.offsetParent).toEqual(!null);
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post your test case code, are you rendering / testing a parent element with a child of my-component?

Comment: Yes. Testing a child element. My test code is really just the above. I created a fixture for the parent element just like you'd find in the Angular Testing docs.

Comment: the component that renders my-component should test if it is displayed or not. Just look for it as a child of the nativeElement. Or give query the dom for it.